# How to replace an element of a symmetric matrix randomly?

Tags: r, sampling, simulation, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like so:

```
data=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.6583,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.6583,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)

     [,1]   [,2] [,3]   [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1 0.0000    0 0.0000    0
[2,]    0 1.0000    0 0.6583    0
[3,]    0 0.0000    1 0.0000    0
[4,]    0 0.6583    0 1.0000    0
[5,]    0 0.0000    0 0.0000    1
```

How do I create another matrix, say "data2", such that it has the same number of off-diagonal nonzero elements as "data" but in another location other than the one in data? The randomly simulated data will be uniform (so runif).

Comment: Will there always be 1s on the diagonal? Is the question for a general square matrix with an unknown number of non-zero values?

Comment: This is a (simulated) partial correlation matrix where I predetermine the number of non-zero off-diagonal elements. Therefore yes, there will always be 1's on the diagonal and it will be a square matrix.

Comment: There are crucial unstated restrictions in this problem: the simulated matrices, if they are to contain correlations, must have off-diagonal values between -1 and 1 and they either must be positive semidefinite or else (if I understand "partial correlation" correctly) must be projections of such matrices (created by zeroing out some pairs of entries).  Also, "uniform" over what parameters? (There are many ways to parameterize these matrices.)

Comment: @whuber Sorry for not being clearer. I use the GGM package (graphical models) to simulate a partial correlation matrix by inputting the # of variables and # of non-zero off-diagonal elements. Say that's for group 1. I would then like another matrix for group 2 (same # of variables and sparsity), but the non-zero element will be different in location and magnitude (i.e., non-zero partial correlation for another 2 variables). I want to see how sensitive my method is under the condition when the 2 groups have same number of variables and sparsity BUT for different variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat clumsy way to do this. It works well for small matrices but would be too slow if you're going to use this for some very high-dimensional problems.

```
# Current matrix:
data=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.6583,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.6583,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)

# Number of nonzero elements in upper triangle:
no.nonzero<-sum(upper.tri(data)*data>0)

# Generate same number of new nonzero correlations:
new.cor<-runif(no.nonzero,-1,1)

# Create new diagonal matrix:
p<-dim(data)[1]
data2<-diag(1,p,p)

### Insert nonzero correlations: ###

# Step 1. Identify the places where the nonzero elements can be placed:

pairs<-(p^2-p)/2 # Number of element in upper triangle
combinations<-matrix(NA,pairs,2) # Matrix containing indices for those elements (i.e. (1,2), (1,3), ... (2,3), ... and so on)

k<-0
for(i in 1:(p-1))
{
    for(j in {i+1}:p)
    {
        k<-k+1
        combinations[k,]<-c(i,j)
    }
}

# Step 2. Randomly pick indices:

places<-sample(1:k,no.nonzero)

# Step 3. Insert nonzero correlations:

for(i in 1:no.nonzero)
{
    data2[combinations[places[i],1],combinations[places[i],2]]<-data2[combinations[places[i],2],combinations[places[i],1]]<-new.cor[i]
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid that the position [2,4] is repeated, you can simply remove those indices from `combinations`

Answer (score 0):

Not really understood the question. There are two off-diagonal and non-zero elements (0.6583) in the example, right? Is matrix with two elements the result you want in this case?

```
data=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.6583,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.6583,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)

# Convert to vector
data2 <- as.numeric(data)

# Remove diagonal
data2 <- data2[as.logical(upper.tri(data) | lower.tri(data))]

# Remove 0 elements
data2 <- data2[data2 != 0]

data2
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. Basically there is one non-zero off-diagonal element on indices [2,4] or [4,2]. I would like "data2" to also have a single non-zero off-diagonal element in its matrix in anywhere OTHER than indices [2,4] or [4,2]. Is that clearer?